# PHP data retrieving problem in database

Tags: php, sql, database

Ok so the problem is... i m a newbie and i m trying to understand what is happening.Im sending through an html form this data(name,email) using POST in a database.I understand the logic behind it all but what basically happens is that everytime I enter a name,any name,it echoes the else statement:"there is already a user with that name". and it sends back the first name in the database.when there s nothing,it sends nothing. So here's the chunk:

```
 $query= "SELECT* from users where username='".$_POST['name']."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result){


        $query = "INSERT into users (username, email, password) values
        ('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["email"]."',  
        '".$passwords[0]."')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if ($result){
            echo "It's entered!";
        } else {
            echo "There's been a problem: ".mysql_error();
        }
     } else {

         echo "There is already a user with that name: <br />";
        $sqlAll = "select * from users";
         $resultsAll = mysql_query($sqlAll);
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($resultsAll);
           while ($row) {

              echo $row["username"]." -- ".$row["email"]."<br />";

           $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Jesus christ _ANOTHER_ SQL injection vulnerability. Where do they all come from...!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: i followed that tutorial from the IBM website.it s a learning tutorial.man,i m just learning about injection.i wouldn t use that on a real site.I m learning!

Comment: @seb: Can you provide a link please? I will write to IBM and ask them to stop promoting this nonsense.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-phptut1/section5.html

Comment: man,it s pissing me off.I think i ll pay somebody to teach.everytime I follow a tutorial or try to use a framework,there s something wrong like with CI where all of a sudden you have to use CI in front of a controller.That s why i decided to ditch frameworks for now and just learn the basics.Sometimes i ll spend a whole day on figuring out why something doesn t work.That was the first time that i asked a question on a board like here!

Comment: @seb: Online tutorials are usually rubbish. Get yourself a good book instead! (BTW, Stack Overflow is not a "board".)

Comment: you re right!it s not a board.I m french so I call everything a board.Seriously,I just realized how great it is.BTW, ethical question.Should I feel bad about downloading books off Mediafire. I understand that the guys are trying to make a living but I just started making some money building websites.I didn t go to school.I take books and practice but anyways.I dont understand how on one side these guys promote open-source software and on the

Comment: other they re mad at "pirates" for giving away their books.

Comment: @seb: Yes. Being an "open source" enthusiast does not mean that they magically do not need to make money (and books are not source code). And just because you can't afford something does not mean you get to have it for free. This is verging on off-topic now, though.

Comment: BTW I wrote to the author of the article; thanks for the link.

Comment: mysql_ will be deprecated in near futrure. use `mysqli_` with prepared statements instead of `mysql_`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check [mysql_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) rather than checking for !$result, I think that if the query is sucsesfull you'll get a resource back, even though it contains zero rows.

You may also want to read up on: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: If `$result == false` then mysql will throw an error with `mysql_num_rows() expected the parameter to be resource but boolean given.`

Answer (score 2):

## ESCAPEEEEE

Firstly, you need to learn about escaping. 
Have you never heard of little Johnny DROP TABLES?

http://xkcd.com/327/

**Serious business**

The reason why it always returns, is because the response in $result is actually a resource data type. And that will always when cast as a boolean be true. (And since your query shouldn't fail).

You should fetch the result. For example. (This isn't the best way, but it is a way to do it).

```
mysql_fetch_row(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [manual](http://us.php.net/mysql_query), mysql_query will return false when there is an error - "For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error."

Answer (score 1):

see no violation in your code. first mysql_query executes with no error and always returns true. try to test returned rows count like this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
//insert record
} else {
// show alreay exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are testing for:

```
if (!$result)
```

which will evaluate to true only if the query fails.

You should also sanitize all input before using it in SQL queries.